shadcn checkbox is not rendering as expected
Problem:
I copied and pasted the Shadcn/UI Checkbox component code from the documentation, but the rendered output does not match the expected result.
Current Output:
The checkbox looks like this:

Expected Output:
The checkbox should look like this:

Steps I Followed:

Copied the exact code snippet for the Checkbox component from the
Shadcn/UI documentation.
Added the required dependencies and ensured
all styles are imported.

Question:
Where might I have gone wrong? The code is identical to the documentation, but the rendered output differs. Is there any configuration or step I might have missed?

I have this exact problem. Didn't have time to look into it today, but if nobody has answered tomorrow and I figure it out, I'll post an answer

Did you figure this one out? Stuck on this as well.

I discovered that some of the css in the default src/index.css was causing this behavior. I solved by removing most of the default css leaving only
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

:root {
    font-family: Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.5;
    font-weight: 400;

    color-scheme: light dark;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.87);
    background-color: #242424;

    font-synthesis: none;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;
    place-items: center;
    min-width: 320px;
    min-height: 100vh;
}

Hope this helps!
